# Can I reduce the file size of all the image tags in my SVGs as a factor of its width and height using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, fabricjs

I am working with importing large SVG photos into my image editor. Some of the SVG images contain `<image>` tags who in turn contain large PNG strings. Some of my files exceed 25MB so that making edits are very slow.

I tried manually scaling / shrink objects it down in the image editor and suddenly the edits were fast, and then I could scale them back up to its original size, seemingly still maintaining the latest edit and without losing any quality (this feels like black magic, could someone explain how this works?)

So this made me think if it is possible to let the system shrink all the images upon loading, but just before showing the new image (most of them are 4500 x 3000 px anyways, so shrinking them by a factor of 4 wouldn't affect its display) and when the user clicks save, we automatically rescale everything to its original size, with the hope of not losing quality, would that even work?

I have tried all kinds of madness to make this work, but nothing bites it seems. Here is my latest attempt. This code is me trying to reduce the pixel size and thus the file size of all the objects.

```
      new Promise(resolve => fabric.loadSVGFromURL(imageUrl, (objects, options) => {
        const group = new fabric.Group(objects)
        objects.forEach(obj => {
            console.log(obj.height)
            var scaleX = obj.scaleX;
            var scaleY = obj.scaleY;
            // Scale to 10% of its original size
            var tempScaleX = scaleX * 0.1;
            var tempScaleY = scaleY * 0.1;
            obj.scaleX = tempScaleX;
            obj.scaleY = tempScaleY;
            obj.height = obj.height * 0.1
            obj.width = obj.width * 0.1
            console.log(obj.height)
        })
        group.height = group.height * 0.1
        group.width = group.width * 0.1
        resolve(getRatio(group, canvas))
      }))
      .then(({ ratio, width, height }) => {
        fabric.loadSVGFromURL(imageUrl, (objects, options) => {
          try {
            objects.forEach(obj => {
              obj.set({
                left: (obj.left * ratio) + ((canvas.width / 2) - ((width * ratio) / 2)),
                top: (obj.top * ratio) + ((canvas.height / 2) - ((height * ratio) / 2)),
              })
              obj.scale(ratio)
              canvas.add(obj)
            })
            canvas.renderAll()
            onCanvasModified(canvas)
          } catch(err) {
            console.log('Could not retrieve that image');
          }
        })
      })
```

Comment: Your SVG is nothing but an **envelope** for (large) Binary image files. You can't make the transport size smaller unless you make those PNGs smaller **before you stick them in the envelope**. Use https://squoosh.app/

Comment: Thank you for the link it is very interesting. I was looking in the tool and I saw that I could only export the result in formats other than SVGs if I want to reduce the size. Is it possible to decrease the size of the Binary image files within the SVG and export that SVG? Have I misunderstood the feature?